# Reading from a data in string without sscanf, in C

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am reading data from an SD card for an STM32 embedded application. This data is written in a text file.

```
char resultFormat[100] = "%s\n%s\n%s\n%lf\n%lf\n%lf\n%i\n%i\n%i\n";

void readResult(int indexNumber)
{
    FRESULT fr;
    FIL MyFile;     /* File object */
    size_t read;
    UINT bytesRead;

    FATFS SDFatFs;  /* File system object for SD disk logical drive */

    fr =  f_mount(&SDFatFs, (TCHAR const *)SDPath, 0); //Mounts the file

    char fileName[20];
    char directory[10] = "RESULTS";
    sprintf(fileName, "%s/%i.TXT", directory, indexNumber);

    fr = f_open(&MyFile, fileName, FA_READ); //Opens the file
    read = f_read(&MyFile, resultBuffer, sizeof resultBuffer, &bytesRead);  //Writes the txt from the txt file to a string.

    vTaskDelay(200);
    f_close(&MyFile); //Closes the file

    sscanf(resultBuffer, resultFormat, resultDate, resultTime, presetName,
           &correctedFlash, &observedFlash, &pressure, &flashedStatus,
           &resultStartTemp, &status);

    sendResultInfo(); //Processes the variables. Not relevant.

    fr = f_mount(NULL, "", 0); //Unmounts the file.
}
```

---

My main question is this:

```
char resultFormat[100] = "%s\n%s\n%s\n%lf\n%lf\n%lf\n%i\n%i\n%i\n";
sscanf(resultBuffer, resultFormat, resultDate, resultTime, presetName,
       &correctedFlash, &observedFlash, &pressure, &flashedStatus,
       &resultStartTemp, &status);
```

I have quite a few variables that need to be read from the string, and if I change anything, I'll also have to change the `resultFormat` which can lead to bugs.

Right now, the number of variables is manageable, but I was wondering how such data should be read if I have more data to be read from the text file, like if I had 100 variables of different types to be read. `sscanf` seems a bit too prone to human error for reliable use in such cases, and I was wondering if there are alternatives to reading data from a string. A previous question provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632621/reading-in-a-multi-line-string-from-a-file-using-sscanf-in-c) offers a solution to long `sscanf` reads, but I am wondering whether there's another solution.

---

My secondary question (unsure if appropriate for this stack, but I get the impression that it would be brought up) is storing this data without using a text file, and not storing it as a string.

Not much of the data I have is a string, some of them are ints and doubles but are stored as a string.

While my current system works (and is good for debugging since I can easily read the data stored, from outside), I was wondering how the non-string data should be formatted and stored in the SD card.

Please let me know if more information or elaboration is required.

Comment: If you are asking more about how to improve this code than how to fix a problem with it consider posting on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You could create a table that contains a conversion format string and a pointer to the variable for every value, then loop over this table and convert the data one-by-one.

Comment: What is `f_open`/`f_write` etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `\n` is almost never needed in a `scanf` format. If you get rid of those you will get a string that is easier to read.
2. *Never* call `scanf` and friends with a format string that is not a string literal. Compiler writers invested a lot of work in catching format errors, but you are throwing it all away by making the actual format string invisible at the call site.
3. Consider using string literal concatenation to align variables with their formats.

A call like

```
sscanf(resultBuffer,
       "%s"        "%s"        "%s"        "%lf"            "%lf"           "%lf"      "%i"            "%i"              "%i",
       resultDate, resultTime, presetName, &correctedFlash, &observedFlash, &pressure, &flashedStatus, &resultStartTemp, &status);
```

is *almost* maintainable. You will get compiler warnings if your mess up the format string so that it no longer corresponds to the actual arguments. You know which part of the format corresponds to which variable by just looking at it. The only problem with it is that it is too long and you cannot split it in several lines without losing visual alignment. If you encounter this problem, split buffer the call into several smaller ones, or move away from `scanf` completely.

Comment: Thank you. 1: Why would getting rid of \n in a string make it easier to read? I understand it from the formatting context but not the context of writing to a txt file.

Comment: 2: The reason I use a variable is because this format is used elsewhere to interpret the same data in a few different places, and I want to make sure that a single change is enough to change the format everywhere. Since adding a "const" to the string, per my understanding, lets the compiler read it like a hard coded value, would that help with letting the compiler catch format errors?

Comment: 1. `\n` serves no purpose in an input format. It's just noise. Noise makes it harder to discern the signal. I wouldn't use the same format string for input and output. 2.  A const string doesn't work with gcc and clang, but a #defined constant works.

Comment: I assume #defined constants would work because they are read at compiler time and treated similarly by the compiler as a string literal?

Comment: Yes that's correct